# Where to put dpm (Devel) to see comment elements?

Tags: comments, debugging

Where to put `dpm` or `dsm` ([Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel)) to see comment elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would put it in comment.tpl.php

```
dpm($content);
```

or in templates.php (located in sites/all/themes/yourtheme) inside a preprocess function

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_comment(&$vars) {
  dpm($vars);
}
```

Upon reading your comment and trying this out myself, looks like devel dpm() doesn't work for comments. As an alternative, you can always use `var_dump($content);` or `print_r($content);` php function.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. Is there a specific place?<?php dpm();>

Comment: @gladiatorhl2 you should probably give that function something to work on - `dpm($content)`

Comment: @gladiatorhl2 updated my answer.

Comment: @NoSssweat : never believe what you haven't seen with your own eyes (or didn't test to ensure it works ...)

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens that is why I usually stay way from code questions to begin with. Sometimes, I want to save my time and do not test things, take a risk and hope I am right. Although, in light of new info/comments, I am always willing to put the time and change my answer.

Comment: "*... willing to change my answer ...*": that sounds like trial-and-error, and might out your (real) reputation at risk ... and result in downvotes like your first revision seems to have triggered ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I am just trying to help out and at the same time save some time. Had gladiator had more rep points I may have questioned my original answer. From the outset, with the very little info that was given, it seemed like a newbie Devel question, don't you agree?

Comment: OK, makes sense ... case (not the question!) closed!

Comment: Looks like my "case closed" needs to be reconfirmed ... which I do now ...

Answer (score 2):

If you can't get `dpm` to work, have a look at the [Devel Debug Log](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_debug_log) module as a possible alternative, which provide the `ddl()` function. Some more details about it (from its project page):

> Devel Debug Log is a developer module that provides a way for developers to save and display debug messages on a separate page in the web browser. It serves as an alternative to using drupal_set_message() or watchdog() for debugging, and a complementary module to Devel for those who find viewing messages in the browser easier than looking for them, say, in a file.
>
> The module provides the ddl($message) function, which the developer can use to save a debug message. If an object or array is supplied as $message, it will be displayed using the Krumo debugging tool. Messages can be viewed at Reports > Debug Messages.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you need dpm() to view all comment properties and then change something before it renders, you can use hook_comment_view().

```
function YOUR_MODULE_comment_view($comment, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  // How old is the comment.
  $comment->time_ago = time() - $comment->changed;   
}
```

More infor here:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21comment%21comment.api.php/function/hook_comment_view/7.x